# getAssets(); from another class

Tags: android, assets

I have a simple read a txt-file function.

```
AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
InputStream is = mngr.open("textdb.txt");
```

It works from my main activity. But if I use the same code in a separate class, getAssets() just return null / crash.

I am unable to find why it only works from the main class.

Any ideas?

**Solution:**

```
subClass.ReadSettings(getApplicationContext());

public String[] ReadSettings(Context myContext) {
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Is your other class also an `Activity`?
getAssets() is a method of Context. If your class is not an activity, you'll need to pass a context into it and then call getAssets on that.

Like so:

```
public myClass(Context myContext) {
    AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
    InputStream is = mngr.open("textdb.txt");
}
```

Comment: No problem! Could you select his answer as the correct answer by clicking the check mark? This deletes the question from the `Unanswered` list and makes it easier for others with the same problem to find a correct answer.