# Trouble opening file with getAssets() inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to write a class that iterates through a textfile, it looks like this (it's ~5000 lines):

```
Postnr  Poststad    Bruksområde Kommunenummer   Lat Lon Merknad Nynorsk Bokmål  Engelsk 
0001    Oslo    Postboksar  301 59.91160    10.75450    Datakvalitet: 2. Koordinatar endra 28.09.2012. Oppdatert 04.12.2012 url1    url2    url3
```

My trouble is: the method getassets is undefined for the type SearchTabTxt

I'm trying to read the file from the assets folder and I can't seem to find a solution to this. I tried to write a search class for this:

```
public class SearchTabTxt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String[]>> {

    protected ArrayList<String[]> doInBackground(String... inputString) {
        ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
            if (is != null) {
                String search = inputString[0].toString();
                InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(is,
                        "UTF-8");
                BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
                int antallTreff = 0;

                while (buffreader.readLine() != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> placeInformation = new ArrayList<String>();
                    if (buffreader.readLine().contains(search)) {
                        antallTreff++;
                        System.out.println("Found: " + search);
                        placeInformation.clear();
                        for (String i : buffreader.readLine().split("\t")) {
                            placeInformation.add(i);
                        }
                        System.out.println(placeInformation.get(11));
                        // Sorry about the Norwegian will rewrite
                        if (antallTreff >= 3) {
                            System.out.println("Did I find something?");
                            break;
                        }
                        if (buffreader.readLine() == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e + "");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e + "");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e + "");

        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's simple. There is no method getAssets() in your SearchTabTxt class. To get the assets, you need a Context. Make a public constructor to your SearchTabTxt class, and pass a Context.

```
private Context context;
public SearchTabTxt (Context myContext) {
    this.context = myContext;
}
```

Now in the doINbackground method you can do:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("file.txt");
```

Now in the Activity when you createyour AsyncTask you can start the task like this: `new SearchTabTxt(this).execute(params);` This works because your Activity (this) is a subtype of Context.
More on this here: [getAssets(); from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458433/getassets-from-another-class)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it's working like a charm now, just a little tuning and I can use it like I want to (found another error, I didn't write to the list, so I didn't get an output) :D