# Why i am getting a NoClassDefFoundError:javax.imageio.ImageIO when trying to get an InputStream from assestManager

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, javax.imageio, android-assets

I have a gfx folder inside assets folder of my Android project, which contains a .png file. When I was trying to get `InputStream` from `assetManager`, I got `NoClassDefFoundError`. The part where I got error is:

```
private void  processImage(){

    try {

        //This is where i got exception when i look from debugger..
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(GameActivity.getActivity().getAssets().open("gfx/" + this.fileName));

        this.imageWidth = image.getWidth();
        this.imageHeight = image.getHeight();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

I looked for what a `NoClassDefFoundError` is, but I couldn't figure it out. What is causing it in my case?

Comment: I don't know Android but when google it shows `getAssets()` is a method of Context class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458433/getassets-from-another-class

Comment: GameActivity.getActivity() returns application context..

Comment: try `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( (GameActivity.getActivity()).getAssets().open("gfx/" + this.fileName));`

Comment: Still it is throwing Error..

Comment: Are you adding in `ImageIO`? This does not come in Android.

Comment: Yeah. Why can't i do that? If not what is the alternative methods to get image Height and Width of a .png file in an android..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't load javax.imageio.ImageIO lib to Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693011/cant-load-javax-imageio-imageio-lib-to-eclipse)