# Read folder name and folder's file name from assets folder

Tags: android, assets

I have this file structure in my android project:

[image]

I want to read all the folder names and their file names contained in assets folder. I have tried so many things but I am not able to achieve my goal. Can somebody guide me to correct direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can read assets folder like **AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();**
   **InputStream is = mngr.open("filename.extention ");**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458433/getassets-from-another-class

Comment: `all the folder names and their file names`? Folder names ok. But if it is a folder then how could it have a file name?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the filenames of a particular folder from assets as follows :

```
private List<String> getFileNames(Context context, String folderName) throws IOException {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        String[] files = assetManager.list(folderName);
        return Arrays.asList(files);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple read all the assets using the below function

```
public myClass(Context myContext) {
    AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
    InputStream is = mngr.open("assests.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple getAssets().list("") will list all folders.

And files if there are. But you havenot.