# How to Use FontAwesome Icon in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, font-awesome

I am developing an xamarin Android application and need to use **FontAwesome** icons in application. But don't know how to use it. Got lot's of articles on internet but it's not clear to me.

How to use FontAwesome icons on Xamarin.Android?

Comment: What have you tried so far, any code you have tried? There are lot of tutorials about adding font awesome to the asset folder and creating a helper class on the interweb.

Comment: Sir I have tried these 2 tutorial's

[tutorial 1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31530/fontawesome-label-heres-how), 
[tutorial 2](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.in/2016/12/use-font-awesome-from-your-xamarinforms.html)

Comment: but as I have tried the code they have provided in these articles It showing me an error under each line of code. `type or namespace could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got worked as below:

Copy `FontAwesome` ttf file to `Assets` folder. Then under `OnCreate()` method of `Activity` page the control should be referred to the font file as below:

**Activity Page:**

```
Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Assets, "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
TextView txtv = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewtitle);
txtv.Typeface = font;
```

**.xaml Page:**

```
<TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:text="\uf238 Unicode To get FontAwesome icon"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#545454"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:padding="6dp"
                  android:id="@+id/textviewtitle"
                  />
```

As you see above in `.xaml` Page code `android:text="\uf238 Unicode To get FontAwesome icon"`, I have declared `\uf238`. This is `unicode` for the particular icon. Every Icon would have unique `unicode`. Therefore we should use always `unicode` character to get any icon displayed on control or on text.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on web use following github repo to get Xamarin.Plugins it has

Font Awesome, Ionicons, Material design icons, Meteocons

https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize

Comment: Sir, there are lots of folders. Which folder should I have to access  ?

Comment: go to following link and read readme https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

Comment: Sir the link that you have shared is for xamarin.Forms App. right ? I need for xamarin.Android. .

Comment: Did you go to last link I commented

Comment: android:text="I {fa-heart-o} to {fa-code} on {fa-android}"   Check readme

Comment: It has defined to use `@Override
    public void onCreate()` now how should I convert it to xamarin ?

Comment: Sir, they have suggested to define **dependencies**. In my application where should I define these dependencies ?

Comment: Sir, I have got 1 reference link as : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210548/how-to-use-icons-and-symbols-from-font-awesome-on-native-android-application). In this referece they have used `getAssets() ` method. What is it ? and how to use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458433/getassets-from-another-class